# How can I transform the .YAML file to a Google Sheet table correctly? .YAML files are not supported for import and online converters didn't work

Tags: google-sheets, type-conversion, yaml

So, I have a static data export file which is only available as a .YAML file. It's pretty large, so here is a piece of the code inside for you to understand how does it look like:

```
2047:
    activities:
        copying:
            time: 720
        invention:
            materials:
            -   quantity: 2
                typeID: 20416
            -   quantity: 2
                typeID: 20415
            products:
            -   probability: 0.34
                quantity: 10
                typeID: 2049
            skills:
            -   level: 1
                typeID: 11529
            -   level: 1
                typeID: 11442
            -   level: 1
                typeID: 23121
            time: 13800
        manufacturing:
            materials:
            -   quantity: 1062
                typeID: 34
            -   quantity: 2
                typeID: 35
            -   quantity: 53
                typeID: 36
            products:
            -   quantity: 1
                typeID: 2046
            skills:
            -   level: 1
                typeID: 3380
            time: 900
        research_material:
            time: 315
        research_time:
            time: 315
    blueprintTypeID: 2047
    maxProductionLimit: 200
26407:
    activities:
        copying:
            materials:
            -   quantity: 10
                typeID: 3812
            skills:
            -   level: 1
                typeID: 26260
            time: 36000
        manufacturing:
            materials:
            -   quantity: 24
                typeID: 25617
            -   quantity: 35
                typeID: 25619
            -   quantity: 1
                typeID: 11486
            -   quantity: 27
                typeID: 25607
            products:
            -   quantity: 1
                typeID: 26406
            skills:
            -   level: 5
                typeID: 3380
            -   level: 1
                typeID: 11449
            -   level: 1
                typeID: 11452
            -   level: 1
                typeID: 26260
            time: 45000
        research_material:
            skills:
            -   level: 5
                typeID: 3409
            -   level: 1
                typeID: 26260
            time: 15750
        research_time:
            skills:
            -   level: 5
                typeID: 3403
            -   level: 1
                typeID: 26260
            time: 15750
    blueprintTypeID: 26407
    maxProductionLimit: 1
31705:
    activities:
        copying:
            time: 1200
        invention:
            materials:
            -   quantity: 1
                typeID: 20424
            -   quantity: 1
                typeID: 20423
            products:
            -   probability: 0.34
                quantity: 1
                typeID: 31711
            skills:
            -   level: 1
                typeID: 11451
            -   level: 1
                typeID: 11452
            -   level: 1
                typeID: 21791
            time: 7200
        manufacturing:
            materials:
            -   quantity: 2
                typeID: 25593
            -   quantity: 4
                typeID: 25601
            -   quantity: 3
                typeID: 25599
            products:
            -   quantity: 1
                typeID: 31704
            skills:
            -   level: 1
                typeID: 3380
            -   level: 1
                typeID: 26257
            time: 1500
        research_material:
            skills:
            -   level: 1
                typeID: 3409
            -   level: 1
                typeID: 26257
            time: 525
        research_time:
            skills:
            -   level: 1
                typeID: 3403
            -   level: 1
                typeID: 26257
            time: 525
    blueprintTypeID: 31705
    maxProductionLimit: 100
```

I want to transform that data into a Google Sheets table, however I faced a problem: I can't use the .YAML file using the "import" function inside the Google Sheets, since .YAML files are not supported.

I tried 20+ different online converters and also tried to convert the .YAML to .CSV, .HTML and other file types what are eligible for Google Sheets import, but it either didn't work with such a large file or the resulting table was missing like half of the content with incorrect data placement among raws and columns.

For now, I don't even think about formatting the data and how do I want the resulting table to look like. I only want to somehow transform that .YAML into a properly working Google Sheet table which is not missing any data.

Please, advise me how would you solve that issue.

P.S.: Also, please keep in your mind that I am absolute 0 to programming, the only thing I can do is copy-paste the code into Google Scripts attached to the Google Sheet and then invoke the containing function. If your solution works separately from GSheets and GScripts environment, please, also advise the actual way how a lamer like me can use it.

Comment: Checkout [softwarerecs.se] or [webapps.se] and see if you're question is ontopic there. Probably your best bet is running it through a local unix/python/nodejs utility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Convert YAML to JSON

This is the data converted to JSON.

```
{
   "2047": {
      "activities": {
         "copying": {
            "time": 720
         },
         "invention": {
            "materials": [
               {
                  "quantity": 2,
                  "typeID": 20416
               },
               {
                  "quantity": 2,
                  "typeID": 20415
               }
            ],
            "products": [
               {
                  "probability": 0.34,
                  "quantity": 10,
                  "typeID": 2049
               }
            ],
            "skills": [
               {
                  "level": 1,
                  "typeID": 11529
               },
               {
                  "level": 1,
                  "typeID": 11442
               },
               {
                  "level": 1,
                  "typeID": 23121
               }
            ],
            "time": 13800
         },
         "manufacturing": {
            "materials": [
               {
                  "quantity": 1062,
                  "typeID": 34
               },
               {
                  "quantity": 2,
                  "typeID": 35
               },
               {
                  "quantity": 53,
                  "typeID": 36
               }
            ],
            "products": [
               {
                  "quantity": 1,
                  "typeID": 2046
               }
            ],
            "skills": [
               {
                  "level": 1,
                  "typeID": 3380
               }
            ],
            "time": 900
         },
         "research_material": {
            "time": 315
         },
         "research_time": {
            "time": 315
         }
      },
      "blueprintTypeID": 2047,
      "maxProductionLimit": 200
   },
   "26407": {
      "activities": {
         "copying": {
            "materials": [
               {
                  "quantity": 10,
                  "typeID": 3812
               }
            ],
            "skills": [
               {
                  "level": 1,
                  "typeID": 26260
               }
            ],
            "time": 36000
         },
         "manufacturing": {
            "materials": [
               {
                  "quantity": 24,
                  "typeID": 25617
               },
               {
                  "quantity": 35,
                  "typeID": 25619
               },
               {
                  "quantity": 1,
                  "typeID": 11486
               },
               {
                  "quantity": 27,
                  "typeID": 25607
               }
            ],
            "products": [
               {
                  "quantity": 1,
                  "typeID": 26406
               }
            ],
            "skills": [
               {
                  "level": 5,
                  "typeID": 3380
               },
               {
                  "level": 1,
                  "typeID": 11449
               },
               {
                  "level": 1,
                  "typeID": 11452
               },
               {
                  "level": 1,
                  "typeID": 26260
               }
            ],
            "time": 45000
         },
         "research_material": {
            "skills": [
               {
                  "level": 5,
                  "typeID": 3409
               },
               {
                  "level": 1,
                  "typeID": 26260
               }
            ],
            "time": 15750
         },
         "research_time": {
            "skills": [
               {
                  "level": 5,
                  "typeID": 3403
               },
               {
                  "level": 1,
                  "typeID": 26260
               }
            ],
            "time": 15750
         }
      },
      "blueprintTypeID": 26407,
      "maxProductionLimit": 1
   },
   "31705": {
      "activities": {
         "copying": {
            "time": 1200
         },
         "invention": {
            "materials": [
               {
                  "quantity": 1,
                  "typeID": 20424
               },
               {
                  "quantity": 1,
                  "typeID": 20423
               }
            ],
            "products": [
               {
                  "probability": 0.34,
                  "quantity": 1,
                  "typeID": 31711
               }
            ],
            "skills": [
               {
                  "level": 1,
                  "typeID": 11451
               },
               {
                  "level": 1,
                  "typeID": 11452
               },
               {
                  "level": 1,
                  "typeID": 21791
               }
            ],
            "time": 7200
         },
         "manufacturing": {
            "materials": [
               {
                  "quantity": 2,
                  "typeID": 25593
               },
               {
                  "quantity": 4,
                  "typeID": 25601
               },
               {
                  "quantity": 3,
                  "typeID": 25599
               }
            ],
            "products": [
               {
                  "quantity": 1,
                  "typeID": 31704
               }
            ],
            "skills": [
               {
                  "level": 1,
                  "typeID": 3380
               },
               {
                  "level": 1,
                  "typeID": 26257
               }
            ],
            "time": 1500
         },
         "research_material": {
            "skills": [
               {
                  "level": 1,
                  "typeID": 3409
               },
               {
                  "level": 1,
                  "typeID": 26257
               }
            ],
            "time": 525
         },
         "research_time": {
            "skills": [
               {
                  "level": 1,
                  "typeID": 3403
               },
               {
                  "level": 1,
                  "typeID": 26257
               }
            ],
            "time": 525
         }
      },
      "blueprintTypeID": 31705,
      "maxProductionLimit": 100
   }
}
```

- [Conversion Tool](https://www.convertjson.com/yaml-to-json.htm)